# How do I run IOMeter using Python?

Tags: python

I am trying to setup test automation.  I would like to run several different sets of IOMeter tests without individually hitting go for all of them.  How do I do that using Python?  If you know a different method, that would work too.  I just have the rest of the test automation setup with Python.

Side note:  can IOMeter record data every 5 seconds for a 30min test?

Answer (score 0):

You can create following batch file on the IOmeter PC and then run it from remote PC:

iometer.bat

```
@echo off
SET sessionid=%1

cd <path-to-iometer>\iometer
psexec \\localhost -i %sessionid% -accepteula -u <domain>\<user> -p <password> cmd /c "<path-to-iometer>\IOmeter.exe" <path-to-iometer>iometer.icf <path-to-iometer>results.csv

@echo on
```

Note (1): you'll need last [psexec](http://download.sysinternals.com/files/PSTools.zip) version installed on your IOmeter PC

Note (2): to get session ID of windows desktop, you'll need to run

```
query session
```

in CMD

If I remember well, recording each 5 seconds is implemented in last 1.1.0